# WPF EventTrigger to modify a control's property values based upon the value of a Property on its Parent Control's View Model changing

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles, prism

I have a `Button` hosted within a `UserControl` which I would like to change the `Background` and `Foreground` properties of whenever the numeric value of a property held within the view model of the `UserControl` changes.

My view model appears as follows (properties and methods removed for brevity).  I am using Prism's `DelegateCommand<T>` for my commands.

```
        public class PianoKeyViewModel : BindingTarget, IPianoKey
        {
            private byte afterTouch;
            private DelegateCommand<AfterTouchEventArgs> afterTouchChangedCommand;

            public byte AfterTouch
            {
                get
                {
                    return afterTouch;
                }
                set
                {
    //Calls a method on BindingTarget to assign to afterTouch and call RaisePropertyChanged.
                    SetProperty(ref afterTouch, value);
                }
            }

            public DelegateCommand<AfterTouchEventArgs> AfterTouchChangedCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    return afterTouchChangedCommand;
                }
                set
                {
    //Calls a method on BindingTarget to assign to afterTouchChangedCommand and call RaisePropertyChanged.
                    SetProperty(ref afterTouchChangedCommand, value);
                }
            }

            protected override void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
            {
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);

                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case nameof(AfterTouch):
                        AfterTouchEventArgs afterTouchEventArgs = new AfterTouchEventArgs(AfterTouch);

                        if (AfterTouchChangedCommand != null && AfterTouchChangedCommand.CanExecute(afterTouchEventArgs))
                            //Executes the AfterTouchChangedCommand since the AfterTouchProperty has just changed and the command exists and can execute.
        AfterTouchChangedCommand.Execute(afterTouchEventArgs);

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

A vastly cut-down version of my XAML for the `UserControl` is as follows.  Note the line below my TODO comment - `AfterTouchChanged` does not exist and needs replacing with a binding to `AfterTouchChangedCommand` which fires the trigger when Execute is called on it.  Also, the `DataContext` of this `UserControl` will be the View Model shown above, this is achieved with a Module utilizing Prism.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.PianoKey.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.PianoKey.View.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:AfterTouchToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="afterTouchToBackgroundColorConverter"/>
        <converters:AfterTouchToForegroundColorConverter x:Key="afterTouchToForegroundColorConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <Button>
            <Button.Triggers>
                <!--TODO: Find out what trigger is needed here to respond to AfterTouchChangedCommand.Execute.-->
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="AfterTouchChanged">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=AfterTouch, Converter={StaticResource afterTouchToBackgroundColorConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=AfterTouch, Converter={StaticResource afterTouchToForegroundColorConverter}}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

What do I need to replace the `EventTrigger` with to get this to update the `Background` and `Foreground` colors of the `Button`?  `DataTrigger` looked promising but as far as I can tell this only works to respond to a single value on a property on the bound source.

Comment: Look into [Storyboards and Animations](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-animations-enteractions-exitactions/). In case this seems not helpfull the `Storyboard`s can reference other elements by name, and you should look into a `DataTrigger` rather than `EventTrigger`.

Comment: Do you want to set the Background and Foreground properties *whenever" the AfterTouch property is set to *any* value? This will only change the properties *once*, right?

Comment: Yes, whenever the AfterTouch value changes I would like to update the Background and Foreground colors.  The value can change an unlimited number of times even during a single button press as it would map to a piano keyboard key's aftertouch feature (which changes based on how hard the key is pushed once held down).

Comment: Regarding the DataTrigger approach the only way I can think that might work is if I were to create a boolean property on my view model which alternated between true and false whenever AfterTouch changed (AfterTouchChangedPoller) and then duplicating the property setter logic on my view for both `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AfterTouchChangedPoller" Value="True">` and `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AfterTouchChangedPoller" Value="False">`.  It would work I guess, but it seems a bit hacky.  I would also have to wrap the AfterTouchChangedCommand in a master command to perform the assignment.